# Python multiplying elements in a list

Tags: python

hello i need help please here is my code

```
num_list = [1,2,3]
 
x = len(num_list)

i = 0
result = 1

while i < x:

  result = result * num_list[0,1,2]
  i = i + 1

print(result)
```

I get this errror

```
<ipython-input-51-e3cc7868b28b> in <module>()
     10 while i < x:
     11   # Step 5: Multiply the 'result' variable with each element of the list. Use list indexing
---> 12   result = result * num_list[1,2]
     13   i = i + 1
     14 # Step 6: Print the result

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Please help. What its supposed to do is multiply all the contents in the list to get a number. Please help.

Comment: `num_list[0,1,2]`. `0, 1, 2` is a tuple, not an integer. If you want the first three indices of the list, you _slice_ it `num_list[0:3]`, but then you'd get an error saying you can't multiply a list with another list in the second iteration of your `while`.

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: Ok so i did what @PranavHosangadi said, and it now needs to be an integer.

Comment: ```TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'```

Comment: IDK why you're surprised -- I told you this would happen. What do you want to achieve with your program?

Comment: list[1,2,3] will give '6'
list[2,3,7] will give '42'

Comment: basically it multiplies all the contents in the list

Answer (score 3):

After reading the answers and comments, try changing `result = result * num_list[0,1,2]` to `result = result * num_list[i]`

Comment: There was also an answer that got deleted, but would have led you to a much cleaner solution. Look into iterating over the list via a for loop. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

From Python’s **version 3.8 to onwards**, you can use `math.prod()` function which just takes values inside an iterable and multiply these until it reaches to end value inside iterable object.

```py
from math import prod
num_list = [1,2,3]
output = prod(num_list)
# 6
```

However, your code had bug which is already covered by **@Pranav Hosangadi**